# Typescript: Generic way to obtain class at runtime from instance

Tags: typescript, inheritance

Considering the following classes, how can I obtain a reference to a class based on a "this" reference?

See the **???** below. I need something that returns the current instance's class. The child class this.type should return the TYPE property of its class. Not that of the parent class.

Thanks,

**parent class**

```
export class TypedAction implements Action {
  static TYPE = [NONE];
  get type (): string {
    return ???; // non generic writing: return TypedAction.TYPE
  }
}
```

**child class** (among many others)

```
export class LoginRequestAction extends TypedAction {
  static TYPE = '[Auth] Login requested';
  constructor(public payload?: { username: string, password: string }){
    super();
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution.

```
export class TypedAction implements Action {
  static TYPE = '[NO TYPE]';
  get type (): string {
    return (<typeof TypedAction>this.constructor).TYPE; 
  }
}
```